# When the column is NULL

Tags: oracle, plsql, null

I have a curious scenario that I have been looking at the last hour and cannot get my head around...

```
CASE WHEN A.ADMIN IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE
    CASE WHEN NULLIF(A.ADMIN, 0.0) = COALESCE(NULLIF(O.QUANTITY, 0.0),NULLIF(O.STRENGTH, 0.0),NULLIF(O.VOLUME, 0.0),NULLIF(O.DOSE, 0.0)) THEN 1
    ELSE 2
    END
END
```

So, the problem is A.ADMIN is the result of an outerjoin and I will never know when it is filled out..but I need to evaluate its result against the first non-null value from table O to see if I should post the 1 or the 2.

Any help appreciated!!
Chris

Comment: So when a.admin is null, you want to return 0, but can you describe in a bit more depth what your goal is with the inner case?

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is already filtered out in first case. So, you don't need to use `NULLIF` in second case.
And `COALESCE` returns first non-null value. Hence you don't need to apply `NULLIF` there too.
Try this :-

```
CASE WHEN A.ADMIN IS NULL 
   THEN 0
ELSE
   CASE WHEN A.ADMIN = COALESCE(O.QUANTITY,O.STRENGTH,O.VOLUME,O.DOSE) 
        THEN 1
   ELSE 2
   END
END
```

Comment: Might want to add a default value, e.g. `0.0`, to the tail end of the `COALESCE`.

Comment: @HABO I think you are right. But I don't know what is the logic if all of the values are null.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but it returns 1 in all cases even when admin is not equal to the result of coalesce.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, had to reverse my thinking:

```
CASE WHEN CMR.ADMIN_DOSAGE = COALESCE(NULLIF(OI.DOSE_QUANTITY, 0.0),NULLIF(OI.STRENGTH,0.0),NULLIF(OI.VOLUME, 0.0),NULLIF(OI.ORDERED_DOSE, 0.0)) THEN 1.00
ELSE 
    CASE WHEN CMR.ADMIN_DOSAGE IS NOT NULL THEN 2.00 END
END
```

Comment: +1 - solved your own problem.  You should also go ahead and accept your own answer, too.

Comment: Can CMR.ADMIN_DOSAGE ever be NULL?